# Appwidget with remoteView Out of memory

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-appwidget

I'm making appwidget but it has Out of Memory error when I set three Animation Drawable at my widget. My AnimationDrawable start with click at different button.

I think it occurs with fulling cache memory stacked with for a click.

Here is my code & error log:

```
 public static RemoteViews rviews;
        rviews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.patpat_widget);
private class ClickHeadAnim implements IAnimatable {
        private int spriteVib = 0;
    public boolean AnimationFinished() {
        return false;
    }

    public void Draw() {
        // Draw the brick at bottom
        int imageResource = mViewContext.Context.getResources().getIdentifier(headAnimePath, "drawable",
            mViewContext.Context.getPackageName());

        if (spriteVib == 0) {
            PatpatView.rviews.setImageViewResource(R.id.patview01,R.drawable.slime_head0);
            PatpatView.rviews.setImageViewResource(R.id.patview01,imageResource);

            spriteVib++;
        } else {
            Log.d("addClickIntent", "Remove head");
            mViewContext.removeAnimatable(this);
            Log.d("addClickIntent", "removeAnimatable: " + this);
        }
    }
}
```

error log

```
03-01 19:53:02.540      809-809/com.teslacoilsw.launcher E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 1149200-byte allocation.
03-01 19:53:03.086      809-809/com.teslacoilsw.launcher E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 1149200-byte allocation.
03-01 19:53:03.094      809-809/com.teslacoilsw.launcher W/AppWidgetHostView﹕ updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
    android.widget.RemoteViews$ActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at android.widget.RemoteViews$ReflectionAction.apply(RemoteViews.java:1272)
            at android.widget.RemoteViews.performApply(RemoteViews.java:2458)
            at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:2417)
            at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetHostView.java:402)
            at o.fl.D(:381)
            at o.fl.updateAppWidget(:636)
            at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost.updateAppWidgetView(AppWidgetHost.java:408)
            at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost$UpdateHandler.handleMessage(AppWidgetHost.java:104)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Comment: What size are the images?

Comment: I'm using 20frame , 10frame , 10frame , 45frame AnimationDrawable  and it's each 98kb, 53.3kb, 53.9kb, 311kb !

Comment: sorry I'm not good at english~ :) AnimationDrawable  consists of each image frame. And all each image size is 350 x 350 pixels. thank you.

Comment: Each image needs about 490K.  You must either scale them when you load them or make them smaller.